# How to implement `Dataframe.value_counts()` without specifing a column name when using `Series.value_counts`

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I get dataframe as follows:

```
    PassengerId   Survived    Pclass    
0   1             0           3 
1   2             1           1 
2   3             1           3
```

And after calling `df.value_counts()` I can get the `value_counts()` of all columns without specifing a column each time, which maybe is like follows:

```
1      1
2      1
3      1
Name: PassengerId, dtype: int64

0      1
1      2
Name: Survived, dtype: int64

3      2
1      1
Name: Survived, dtype: int64
```

I am wondering how to implement it.
Could anyone help me?
Thanks in advances.

Comment: `df.apply(pd.value_counts)`?

Comment: I think jezrael's `SeriesGroupBy.value_counts` is what I exactly want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 solutions with [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for apply function per columns, but indices are aligned by their intersection, so `NaN`s are added:

```
df1 = df.apply(pd.value_counts)
print (df1)
   PassengerId  Survived  Pclass
0          NaN       1.0     NaN
1          1.0       2.0     1.0
2          1.0       NaN     NaN
3          1.0       NaN     2.0

df1 = df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
print (df1)
   PassengerId  Survived  Pclass
0          NaN       1.0     NaN
1          1.0       2.0     1.0
2          1.0       NaN     NaN
3          1.0       NaN     2.0
```

For avoid it is possible use [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html):

```
df1 = df.stack().groupby(level=1).value_counts().rename_axis(('a','b')).reset_index(name='c')
print (df1)
             a  b  c
0  PassengerId  1  1
1  PassengerId  2  1
2  PassengerId  3  1
3       Pclass  3  2
4       Pclass  1  1
5     Survived  1  2
6     Survived  0  1
```

Or original solution with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df1 = (df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
         .stack()
         .astype(int)
         .rename_axis(('a','b'))
         .reset_index(name='c')
print (df1)
   a            b  c
0  0     Survived  1
1  1  PassengerId  1
2  1     Survived  2
3  1       Pclass  1
4  2  PassengerId  1
5  3  PassengerId  1
6  3       Pclass  2
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is using `melt`

```
df.reset_index().melt('index').groupby('index').value.value_counts()
Out[608]: 
index  value
0      0        1
       1        1
       3        1
1      1        2
       2        1
2      3        2
       1        1
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following code:

```
d={'PassengerId':pd.Series([1,2,3]),
  'Survived':pd.Series([0,1,1]),
  'Pclass':pd.Series([3,1,3])}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)

s=[]
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    s.append(pd.Series(df.apply(pd.value_counts).values[:,i]).dropna())
print('\nvalue counts each column:')
print(s)
```

Output:

```
   PassengerId  Survived  Pclass
0            1         0       3
1            2         1       1
2            3         1       3

value counts each column:
[1    1.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
dtype: float64, 0    1.0
1    2.0
dtype: float64, 1    1.0
3    2.0
dtype: float64]
```